# D8 warnings что это за ошибки?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

D8 warnings что это за ошибки при компиляции проекта  ?

Answer (score 2):

[D8](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/d8) это утилита, которая `.class` файлы JVM формата перекомпилирует в `DEX` файлы ART/Dalvik VM, на которой собственно и работает Android.

В данном конкретном случае предупреждения показывают, что `.class` файлы по каким-то причинам не удается перекомпилировать в `DEX` ввиду отсутствия указанных внешних ссылок.

В случае с EasyMock надо включить либу `dexmaker`

Comment: У меня включен proguard-rules  а  в нем -keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; } это может быть причиной?

Comment: А как включить либу dexmaker?

Comment: 1) Уберите на этапе отладки `proguard`
2) Вчитайтесь в доки `easymock` - там все написано